# why i can't make a proper instance of materalSkin.materialCard dynamically in c# windows form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I did try to make a `MaterialSkin.materialCard` in C# windows form dynamically and everything was fine until I gave a location to it.

When I gave a location to it the Y position was the one I gave but for the X it was just set on a X position no matter what I gave to it. For example, I give 100 for X but in the form it appeared with 30.

This is the code I have been working on:

```
var Messages = dbMessages.messages.Where((i) => i.from == fromID && i.to == toID).ToList();

int top = 10;
foreach (var item in Messages)
{
    MaterialCard Text = new MaterialCard();
    Text.Name = item.text;
    Text.Size = new Size(103, 34);
    Text.Margin = new Padding(14, 14, 14, 14);
    Text.Padding = new Padding(14, 14, 14, 14);
    Text.Location = new Point(200,200);
    Text.Top = top;
    Text.Visible = true;
    this.Controls.Add(Text);

    top += 50;
}
```

Comment: what is `this` in you code sample? A form? Also, you are setting the Y twice with `Location` and `Top`.

Comment: "this" is a form and for the top it is because to the materialcards don't stick together can have a gap between them

Comment: You could set the Y with `Text.Location = new Point(200,top)` then and leave the additional assignment away. And what is the value for the card's X in this code sample?

Comment: this is just a random number to see it on my screen

Comment: I meant what X is for the card, the position.

Comment: new Point(200,200); i set 200 for X in position

Comment: The question in combination with your comments make no sense to me. Please double check if you have given all the info you have and form a question you want to be answer. Like "Why is it like THIS if I do THAT, I would have expected THOSE results"

Comment: i'm sorry for the lack of information,I am trying to say when i make an instance of a text the X in the location will set to forexample 30 despite the value i give and the code you gave it is working so thanks